# jQuery UI .sortable very jumpy

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using nested sortables to create a UI editor. Basically similar to portlets I guess. The user picks up widgets or widget holders and can move them around the screen, then it saves. They are really jumpy and don't like to stick into certain spots. It almost seems like they prefer to be dragged top-down. I've tried adding padding to the holder and the widgets and it doesn't seem to make it any better. Does anyone know of a really good method of making this crap more accurate? I've tried almost everything I can find....I understand the issue (mostly), I just can't figure out a fix. One problem is when it snaps into a spot, something moves and sometimes what moves makes the layout change drastically and the placeholder jumps back and forth trying to settle. I don't understand why I can't get it to go to the top of a holder though...Here's my js:

```
  $(".widget_holder").sortable({
        distance: 30,
        revert: true,
        items: ".widget",
        opacity: .8,
        scroll: true, 
        scrollSensitivity: 100, 
        scrollSpeed: 100,
        handle: ".move_widget",
        dropOnEmpty: true,
        tolerance: "pointer",
        cursorAt: { top:0, left: 0 },
        start: function(e, ui){
        $(".widget_holder", ui.item).hide();
        $('.widget').addClass("drag_padding");
        $(".widget_holder" ).addClass("holder_hover").addClass("drag_padding").sortable("refresh");
        },
        update: function(e, ui){
        if(this === ui.item.parent()[0]) {
        updateByHolder();
        }
        },
        stop: function(e, ui){
        $(".widget_holder", ui.item).show();
        $('.widget').removeClass("drag_padding");
        $(".widget_holder" ).removeClass("holder_hover").removeClass("drag_padding");
        }
   }).sortable(
       "option", "connectWith", '.widget_holder' 
    );
```

Comment: Can you provide the link to the site where you tried this? I think it could be a CSS problem.

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot find anything to drag around on the site you provided.

Comment: Hover over a widget and it has three popup buttons. The left one is drag to move. (popups on the bottom right are for the holder, top left are for the widget) If you don't see them, what browser are you using? I may need to fix for that one. I'm using chrome and it works.

Comment: I do not have any hover effect on the widgets. Do you have to be logged in?

Answer (score 1):

Try getting rid of `tolerance: "pointer",` or replace it with `tolerance: "intersect",`

Having `pointer` as the `tolerance` options makes the whole list very jumpy!

Comment: I'll try that when I get back to this part of the service. I started from scratch to make the interface a lil easier to understand/navigate. Now that I've almost gotten back to where I was, I'll be back to working on this within a week or two.

Comment: Sure! Good luck and hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

What about `overflow: auto;` to the parent (ul, #element_id, etc)?